# How do debt settlement plans work?

Tags: debt-restructuring

Let's say that you owe $10,000 to several creditors. You can't pay the whole amount, but you do have enough on hand to offer everyone 40-60 cents on the dollar. And there are debt settlement companies that (for a fee, taken at the "back" end), can negotiate such large discounts.

What allows this to happen? Is it because the creditors will take a larger "haircut" than, say, 40-50 cents on the dollar if they sell it to debt buyers, etc.? Does that give them an incentive to settle?

Are there instances where creditors will sell their debt to third parties for less than what they are offered in settlement? Are debtors given the right of first refusal if creditors do decide to sell their debt?

Comment: They typically move all your debt into one new loan, adding their bill to it, and you are then left to pay off that new loan. The new loan would have a much better rate than the usual credit card debt people get stuck with, so you'd pay less per month than before, but you still have to pay it off. You don't get anything for free.

Comment: It depends on where you are. Here, the debt settlement "company" is a subsidiary of the central bank and is owned by the government. The government passed several laws giving the debt settlement agency the power to force debtors to cancel all interests and fees related to the debt leaving you owing only the principal. A plan is then drawn up for you to pay the remaining amount. If it is not possible for you to follow the plan you will then have to file for bankruptcy (which is the traditional "debt settlement plan" system enforced by the courts). So in my case it happens because it is the law

Comment: In the UK you don't *need* to use a 3rd party, there are template letters you can use at places like Citizens Advice etc.

Comment: In the USA these companies tend to be scams, not settling debt and not clearing your credit report, but merging your debt into a different debt and charging you a fortune to do so.  Those adverts aren't free lol, it's just more taking advantage of the disadvantaged.   There are a few genuine credit counselors, that are nonprofits - look up the company name on Guidestar.org, if they're not there, scam.

Answer (score 21):

As unsecured debt becomes more delinquent the likelihood it will be repaid  decreases. There are various debt collection routes that can be taken, but typically it gets to someone willing to settle for a fraction of the debt because they're either prepared to write it off as uncollectable or sell the debt off to a third party for a fraction of the original amount.

Typically the only way to have any bargaining power with unsecured debt is to first stop paying so the account becomes delinquent 120+ days. You tank your credit score, and make the creditors doubt they'll get anything from you. At that point to settle for less than you owe you'd also need a lump sum to offer.

Practices may vary by debt settlement companies, but my understanding is that if you have a lump sum they just negotiate on your behalf to settle your debt for say 40% of original debt but you pay them 50% of the original amount so they make 10%. If you don't have a lump sum they set up an account that you can pay into monthly, then when your account has sufficient balance to make a lump sum payment against one of your debts they'd negotiate that debt and pay it off, basically an escrow account. They are not extending you credit (you're not credit-worthy).

These debt settlement companies aren't protecting your credit score, it has to be tanked to have a chance to settle for a fraction of original amount. They aren't likely saving you any money, you could negotiate the same reduced payment and skip paying the settlement company. They also aren't protecting you from any legal action that a creditor may take to collect (some might offer legal services if you get sued, for an extra fee, but they aren't doing anything that would stop it from happening).

This is very different from debt consolidation which is a new loan used to pay off other debts but at a (hopefully) lower interest rate. You can go through debt consolidation without tanking your credit score.

It's also worth noting that just like debt collection companies, debt settlement companies have been known to employ shady business practices/offer poor advice. Bankruptcy can be a better option for some people that feel trapped by debt.

Comment: And some of these just took your money. News ...

Comment: I think this is pretty good. But may I suggest a short paragraph explaining that [in the US at least] the debtor is going to be issued an IRS 1099 form for the amount forgiven? So you got $50,000 forgiven, but your tax bill for this year is going to cause a nosebleed.

Comment: @AldusBumblebore It's a good point, that's one of the reasons bankruptcy may be a better option. I was trying not to cover too much as it already felt like a long answer. Definitely anyone should further research bankruptcy pros/cons if they are overwhelmed by debt to learn more.

Comment: @HartCO I personally appreciate long answers and I don't think the 'SE ethos' generally disfavors them per se as a detailed and comprehensive answer is (or can be) very valuable, even if length is, in some sense, a 'cost' that we should be trying (somewhat) to minimize. I've written some fairly long answers myself and I think maybe the only significant 'mitigation' that's warranted, generally, is to deliberately structure/organize the answer to be as readable as possible/feasible.

Answer (score 3):

Creditors sell off uncollectable debt all the time to debt collectors, many times for pennies on the dollar. In those situations, almost every dollar they are able to get from you are pure profit. The original creditor does this under the assumption that they at least get SOME money that they otherwise probably wouldn't recover.

You do not get any right of refusal in the matter.

Comment: Would many creditors be inclined to make a deal with the debtor for, say, 50 cents on the dollar instead of "pennies?"

Comment: Debt collectors certainly would, because anything they recover is almost pure profit. Creditors not as much. In either case your credit would probably take a big hit for settling less than the full amount.

Comment: @TomAu Look at this this way: if a debtor owes $10k and has no intent to ever pay it back in full, the creditor is out $10k, but if they sell the debt for $1k, at least they're only out $9k. The collector is out $1k hoping they'll negotiate some steep discount, like $5k, which is $4k profit. And, of course, they're obviously making money on average, or they wouldn't be in business. The creditor reduces their losses, the collectors stand to make bank off bad debt.